# Using SHOW CREATE TABLE in a subquery

Tags: mysql

I want to get the script of existing table and assign to variable and save it in db.
I have used this script

```
SELECT `CreateTable` FROM (show create table tablename);
```

But it is not working

I want createtable column from the result plz review the result image:
[image: I want createtable column from the result plz review the result image]

if there is other way to get script of table also mention it.

Comment: Note the space in the column name.

Comment: Please don't say "not working", show us the **exact error message you got**.

Comment: it will give read squiggling

Comment: When you run it you get a very specific error message. The squiggles are just a heads up.

Comment: I'm not sure that `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is something you can use in a subquery. Can you fetch this in your application layer, then insert it back in once you've extracted the value?

Comment: im just creating procedure there is no application layer